# Trying to read file into dynamically allocated 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, 2d, allocation

I am trying to read a file into a dynamically allocated 2d array but I keep getting the same line printed out. The file I am putting into this code is a .txt with 1000 lines. The print at the end is to check if the array is getting the right data. And lastly I am trying to realloc as the code goes to fit the number of lines to put into arrays. THANKSS :)

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>



int main(void)
{
    char buffer[349];
    char *del = "";
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int len = 100;
    int row = 10;
    int max = 10;
    char** d;

    d = malloc(row * sizeof(char*));

    for(i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        d[i] = malloc(349);
    }
    i = 0;



    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        d[i] = buffer;
        i++;
        if(i == max)
        {
            d = realloc(d, sizeof(d)*2);

            for(i = max; i <= max*2; i++)
            {
                d[i] = malloc(349);
            }
            max = max * 2;
            printf("reallocating to %d\n", max);
        }

    }

    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {   
        printf("%s\n", d[i]);
        printf("%lu\n", sizeof(d[i])); 
    }
}
```

Sample line on txt file:

2152,1,MAIN,SOCW,6390,006,22913,IND  - Independent Study,0,1,1,0,0,12:00 AM,12:00 AM,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,01-20-2015,05-08-2015

And there are about 1000 lines like these in the file.

Comment: 1)`d[i] = buffer;` change to `strcpy(d[i], buffer);`

Comment: 2)`d = realloc(d, sizeof(d)*2);` --> `d = realloc(d, sizeof(*d)*max*2);`

Comment: 3)`for(i = max; i <= max*2; i++)` --> `for(i = max; i < max*2; i++)`

Comment: 4) `printf("%lu\n", sizeof(d[i]));` --> `printf("%lu\n", strlen(d[i]));`

Comment: 5)this part `i` to other variable `for(int j = max; j < max*2; j++){ d[j] = malloc(349);}`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY 4) `printf("%lu\n", strlen(d[i]));` --> `printf("%zu\n", strlen(d[i]));` ... also, I believe 5 is a non-issue.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour yes, It was speculated that there may be a reason that can not be used.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour (5) `i` of (3) becomes impossible Reading continues by used for other purposes.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Fair enough, but `printf("%lu\n", strlen(d[i]));` is undefined behaviour...

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour There is a track record of already using. :D Performing a cast if necessary.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  I corrected my mistakes but i get an error. I added a sample string to the end of my post if that helps. Appreciate it guys!

Comment: @sukurity Please specific description of the error.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY it prints "reallocating to 20" then prints "segmentation fault: 11"

Comment: Did you make (5) fixes?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY `d = realloc(d, ...);` is also an error.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour it is said that when realloc fails?

Answer (score 0):

`d` doesn't look like a '2D array' of anything. Arrays are contiguous. Your allocations aren't. I recommend that you change the type of `d` and avoid excessive allocations.

```
char (*d)[349] = NULL;
size_t d_size = 0;
```

Check if `d_size` is a binary power (a power of `2`) to determine when to resize, and resize by doubling:

```
if ((d_size & (d_size + 1)) == 0) {
    void *temp = realloc(d, (2 * d_size + 1) * sizeof *d);
    if (temp == NULL) {
        perror(realloc);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    d = temp;
}
```

Because `d` starts off `NULL` and `d_size` a binary power (`0`), the capacity check needs to go before the assignment. You can eliminate `buffer` as a result.

There is no need to store the capacity of `d`, since we know it'll be the first binary power we get to by incrementing `d_size` repeatedly. `d_size` becomes your `i`, if you like.

---

That aside, BLUEPIXY gave the solution to your problems in comments. With one correction, those were:

1. `strcpy(d[i], buffer);`
2. `d = realloc(d, sizeof(*d)*max*2);`
3. `for(int j = max; j < max*2; j++){ d[j] = malloc(349);}`
4. `printf("%zu\n", strlen(d[i]));`

At least these four are required to get your program *working* (whatever that means), but you should also think about these two:

- When `d = realloc(d, ...);` fails and returns `NULL`, what happens to your previous value of `d`? It leaks into thin air. You should store the return value of `d` into a `temp` variable (eg. below) and check for `NULL` before you proceed.
- Don't forget to `free` any memory you've `malloc/realloc`'d.

---

Integrating what few of those still apply into what I've learnt so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char (*d)[349] = NULL;
    size_t d_size = 0;

    for (;;)
    {
        if ((d_size & (d_size + 1)) == 0)
        {
            void *temp = realloc(d, (2 * d_size + 1) * sizeof *d);
            if (temp == NULL)
            {
                break;
            }
            d = temp;
        }

        if (fgets(d[d_size], sizeof d[d_size], stdin) == NULL) {
            break;
        }

        d_size++;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < d_size; i++)
    {   
        printf("%s\n", d[i]);
        printf("%zu\n", strlen(d[i])); 
    }

    free(d);
}
```